# r data.table: aggregating the grouping column inconsistency

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using data.table package to aggregate a column which is also a grouping column. But the results are not what I expected.

```
my_data =  data.table(contnt=c("america", "asia", "asia","europe", "europe", "europe"), num= 1:6)

#my_data
#contnt  num
#america  1
#asia     2
#asia     3
#europe   4
#europe   5
#europe   6

my_data[, length(contnt),by=contnt]
#contnt  V1
#america  1
#asia     1
#europe   1
```

It works differently when I aggregate a column other than grouping column

```
my_data[, length(num),by=contnt]
#contnt  V1
#america  1
#asia     2
#europe   3
```

What causes this discrepancy?

Comment: You probably want `my_data[, .N,by=contnt]`

Comment: Thanks Mike, that works fine. But I was interested in why there's an inconsistency.

Answer (score 6):

This is a great example to demonstrate the way data.table passes grouping variables vs. other variables to functions:

```
my_data[,print(contnt),by=contnt]
# [1] "america"
# [1] "asia"
# [1] "europe"

my_data[,print(num),by=contnt]
# [1] 1
# [1] 2 3
# [1] 4 5 6
```

Essentially, grouping variables are passed as vectors of length 1 for each group, whereas for other variables, the entire vector for each group is passed.

Answer (score 3):

Please study the [`data.table` FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html):

> **Inside each group, why are the group variables length-1?**
>
> [...] `x` is a grouping variable and (as from v1.6.1) has length 1 (if inspected or used in `j`). It's *for efficiency and convenience*. [...]
>
> If you need the size of the current group, use `.N` rather than calling `length()` on any column.