# Same j as by in datatable leads to strange outcome

Tags: r, data.table

Let's keep this simple. I have the following DT:

```
library(data.table)
test <- setDT(data.frame(a=c(1,2,2,1,3,3,3,4,4,4),b=c(1:9,9)))

test[a == 4,sum(b),b]
```

gives:

```
   b V1
1: 8  8
2: 9  9
```

but why? Should the sum of the second row not be equal to 18? If I use first:

```
test[a == 4]
```

we get

```
   a b
1: 4 8
2: 4 9
3: 4 9
```

so clearly, the sum of b by the second b group should be 18. What am I missing? Note: I am not saying that command makes much sense, but I am trying to understand it at this time.

Comment: I'm not sure I have a particularly good explanation, but `test[a == 4, sum(b), by=b, verbose=TRUE]` gives some information like "*Detected that j uses these columns: <none>*", suggesting that nothing is being used in the `j` part of `test[i, j, by]`

Comment: @thelatemail thanks, this is interesting. But I still dont understand. `sum(b)` is used for `j`, why does it say `<none>`

Comment: I'm hoping one of the *data.table* authors can appear here and shed some light, as I'm not really sure how to explain it either. I'm hunting for previous questions to see if this has been discussed elsewhere.

Comment: I've deleted my earlier answer; I don't grasp it well enough.

Comment: When you group by a variable, it shows up as length 1 in j. Try `test[a==4, {print(.GRP); print(.BY); print(.SD)}, by=b]` to see -- columns from by= are made available in .BY and other columns are in .SD. You can also use .N (the group size) for your calculation if needed.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63359096/n-differs-from-lengthvariable-when-variable-is-used-in-by

Comment: See [data.table FAQ 2.10](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#inside-each-group-why-are-the-group-variables-length-1). Dupe-oid: [r data.table: aggregating the grouping column inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745706/r-data-table-aggregating-the-grouping-column-inconsistency/46753384#46753384)

Comment: Thanks everyone for who posted useful links or added useful comments. At least, I understand now what causes this behavior. I think the logical consequence how to best handle this issue is given in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't `sum` and `group` with the same column `b`, otherwise you will always get a new column `V1`, whose value is same with the group column `b`, because each value in group column `b` is unique, which means you will get it self if you `sum` by an unique value in `b` (`V1 = b`) . For your purpose,
you can group with a new variable `rleid(b)`, which marks different groups.

```
dt = data.table(a=c(1,2,2,1,3,3,3,4,4,4),b=c(1:9,9)))
dt[a == 4, .(a = unique(a), b = unique(b), sumb = sum(b)), by = rleid(b)]
#   rleid     a     b  sumb
#   <int> <num> <num> <num>
#1:     1     4     8     8
#2:     2     4     9    18
```

P.S. You can also have a better understanding if you create a copy of column  `b` with `dt[,c:=b]` and then try `dt[a == 4,sum(b),c]`

```
dt[,c := b][a == 4,sum(b),c]
#       c    V1
#   <num> <num>
#1:     8     8
#2:     9    18
```